# Does resetting the rating on an app also reset the top "Most Helpful" rated reviews?

Tags: ios-appstore

I have an app that hasn't had the ratings on it reset in almost a year. During that time it has accumulated a large amount of healthy 5 star ratings/reviews. However, the top review that shows on the app store product listing is a 1-star lengthy review. This 1-star review was at one time a 5-star and managed to accumulate enough "Helpful" votes to land it's way to the top of the reviews for the app. In a stroke of what I see as bad luck, the owner of this top review changed their rating to 1-star. So now when you visit the app page, you see this 1-star review. I am now trying to figure out a way to remove it. Reporting it does not do anything.

So my question, if I reset the rating when I submit a new update, will it also reset the top "Most Helpful" reviews?

Comment: What did you find out?

Comment: In the end, I ended up NOT resetting the rating. I would imagine doing so would not remove the top rating since it is across all versions of the app. I ended up repeatedly reporting the "most helpful" review until they eventually removed it. I typed up a fairly long removal request. I made sure to be thorough and present a case as to why it should be removed and then they accepted my appeal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the rating of "Most helpful" reviews, but according to https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/ it does not not reset your apps' written reviews.

> In addition, keep in mind that resetting your summary rating does not
>   reset your app’s written reviews. Past reviews will continue to
>   display on your product page.